# Rename modules and update imports in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I have noticed that VSCode does not warn me when I rename a folder or module that all files that import it will be modified and does not update the imports of that module in other modules where it is used.
Until not too long ago I remember that VSCode could automatically update the imports of a module or package when it was renamed, so that I didn't have to do it manually. Until I noticed that it doesn't come up, I would get a dialog box warning me that some files will stop working correctly by renaming a module, now it just renames it but doesn't update the imports, without warning me of the changes.

Have they removed that function or maybe I just disabled it unintentionally?

In case it is relevant I have in the working directory a .vscode folder where I configure peacock and little else, I don't think it affects anything.

This is the settings.json inside the .vscode folder:

```json
{
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBar.activeBackground": "#325abe",
        "activityBar.background": "#325abe",
        "activityBar.foreground": "#e7e7e7",
        "activityBar.inactiveForeground": "#e7e7e799",
        "activityBarBadge.background": "#de819b",
        "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#15202b",
        "commandCenter.border": "#e7e7e799",
        "sash.hoverBorder": "#325abe",
        "statusBar.background": "#274796",
        "statusBar.foreground": "#e7e7e7",
        "statusBarItem.hoverBackground": "#325abe",
        "statusBarItem.remoteBackground": "#274796",
        "statusBarItem.remoteForeground": "#e7e7e7",
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#274796",
        "titleBar.activeForeground": "#e7e7e7",
        "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#27479699",
        "titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#e7e7e799"
    },
    "peacock.color": "#274796"
}
```

I have tried deleting the .vscode folder just in case that's what it is, even though the settings I make do not affect the VSCode editor settings and nothing.